# How to add another (name) criteria to =AVERAGEIFS?

Tags: excel, formula

Can someone advise me how to add additional criteria to this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(amounts,dates,">="&F5,dates,"<="&EOMONTH(F5,0))
```

Additional criteria would be the name of a person e.g. Adam Smith. The point is to get the `name` of a particular person associated with a specific `month in specific year` and `average of data` in this particular month.

Thanks
West

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=AVERAGEIFS(amounts,dates,">="&F5,dates,"<="&EOMONTH(F5,0),names,G5)
```

Change `G5` with the cell having name.

Comment: just one last question, and if I want to add another criteria after ...names,G5  I will go with: ,anothercriteria,A1) ?

Comment: @WestRay - Right. You can add as many `criteria_range,criteria` in `AVERAGEIFS`. Syntax is `AVERAGEIFS(average_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, criteria_range2, criteria2, criteria_range3, criteria3, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Add another pair of parameters, one which gives the range of the names and another which gives the name you want to find. If you define a range called names then you could add:

```
,names,G5
```